# TCP and UDP are using different OS Buffer?

Tags: windows, tcp, udp, winsock

HI all.

Here is the scenario.

I have port 8888 for my program to use.

I build a TCP and a UDP listener on that port. (This can do, c# allows, because they are two different protocols)

My question is

If the network traffic is very busy, TCP sockets may refuse or signalling the other end to stop sending things, it is called congestion control, right?

So if TCP is congestion controlling, other ends may not send more data, in this "TCP quiet period", UDP channel should have not that much of traffic, right?

I want to figure out the TCP traffic will affect UDP traffic or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TCP and UDP traffic can affect each other, since they are both IP traffic.  Intermediate routers will not distinguish between the two, and if there is congestion, either may be dropped.  It makes no difference what the port is.

TCP may tend to reduce its transmission rate at the sender due to congestion control if packets are being dropped, while UDP will tend to just drop packets.

What are you really asking?

Comment: Thanks WhirlWind. I just want to figure out, for example, if many TCP connections are made and being used in a heavy way, will UDP survive from this kind of congestion?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "survive."  Some UDP segments may be lost.

Comment: Some UDP datagrams may ALWAYS be lost even if there's no other traffic - you should design assuming you WILL always have missing and duplicate datagrams from UDP.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the explicit question in the title...

TCP and UDP have different buffers but they both talk to IP which has one buffer in the kernel and are generally considered equal as the packets get routed over the network.

So TCP and UDP will not interact at the "transport" layer but will interact at the "network", "datalink", and "physical" layers beneath that.